# storing user detail ... session vs cache !

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to save per user information in a place that is the best (meening performance, resources, security etc... for a scallable application) witch is the best for doing so.. session or cache? (ASP MVC)

Comment: so i should query the info every time i want it? doesnt that involve alot of access to the database?

Comment: Which method you use also depends on how much data you're storing. A few smalls strings - cookie or session is fine. Larger data set, use a hidden field as below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

Caching will work, but it doesn't do a good job on per-user information; it tends to be application-global information. Session works, but you may run into concurrency issues. http://blog.whiletrue.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-sessions-and-concurrent-requests-not-what-youd-expect/

I've had good experience with getting information from the database, loading it into a model, and then keeping what I need through the page in hidden variables (Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyField)). This makes the page stateless and you don't have to worry about session timeout; however, it is not that secure. Kind of a ViewState-on-the-cheap. :-).

Comment: Try encrypting the information stored in the hidden field... and you`ll greatly secure your "view state"

Comment: If you're sending data to the client like this, you really should encrypt it, or at least include a hash so you can ensure the data isn't tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for store the data session and database.

Answer (score 0):

For persisting (storing) User Information (such as an address, for example), I would go with a profile provider!

A cache can expire after an amount of time, and can be accessed by the entire application. So for reliability and security, session is more suited to a user based environment, as its what it was developed for.

If you need any more information, just let me know!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The session is more appropriate and isolated for that one user (ie you can't access the session of another user from someone else's session). You can also use a database server as a session store if you need to access it from multiple web servers like in a web farm environment.